# returning two XML nodes at once

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to obtain a list of `qux` attributes of siblings with a certain attribute, in this case `x` in attribute `foo` and `y` in attribute `foo` of it's sibling.

```
//node[@foo="x" and following-sibling::node[@foo="y"]]/@qux | //node[@foo="y" and preceding-sibling::node[@foo="x"]]/@qux
```

This creates a list, but is the same as running both parts separately and adding them together, except for the order. I need a list of both `qux` next to eachother, so a list of two `qux` elements per row, obviously where the siblings match up.

Can this be done in xpath, and if so, how? If not, would xquery do the job?

edit: sample file and output:

```
<database>
  <ds version="1">
    <node>
     <node foo="x" qux="hello"/>
     <node foo="y" qux="world"/>
    </node>
  </ds>
  <ds version="1">
    <node>
     <node>
       <node foo="x" qux="another"/>
       <node foo="y" qux="sentence"/>
       <node foo="y" qux="example"/>
       <node foo="z" qux="irrelevant"/>
     </node>
    </node>
  </ds>
  <ds version="1">
    <node>
      <node foo="y" qux="not"/>
      <node foo="z" qux="returned"/>
    </node>
  </ds>
</database>
```

Note that the depth of the node I'm interested in isn't known, so (I think) usage of //node is necessary.

A query should return:

```
hello world
another sentence
another example
```

Comment: This can be produced by a single XPath 2.0 expression. It cannot be produced by a single XPath 1.0 expression. In case you'd be interested in the XPath 2.0 solution, please, let me know.

Comment: I am interested in your solution, I don't really care if it's XPath 1.0, XPath 2.0 or something else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the OP's expressed interest in an XPath 2.0 solution:

**This XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
for $n in //node[@foo eq 'x' and following-sibling::*[1][self::node[@foo eq 'y']]]
 return
   ( ($n|$n/following-sibling::*[1])/@qux/string(), '&#xA;')
```

**produces the wanted result**.

Answer (score 1):

Its not so easy to get your results with a single XPATH statement- XPATH is intented for XML navigation really. XSL is used for XML transformations (which is really what you want to do, i.e. transform an attribute list [hello][world] into a string "hello world"..) SO here is the XSL you need to get the results you want-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?altova_samplexml file:///C:/Users/Damien/Desktop/testXML.xml?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"  
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-
functions">
<xsl:template match="/">    
    <xsl:for-each select="//node[@foo='x' and following-
 sibling::node[@foo='y']]/@qux | //node[@foo='y' and preceding-
 sibling::node[@foo='x']]/@qux">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This does not make sure the foo='y' node matches up in the two clauses, it can be a different node that also happens to have foo='y'. Also, I don't think this could just be accomplished by running the xpath and removing all newline characters, right? I appreciate your input. I've slightly altered my original post to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

For lack of complete understanding of the requirements, but wouldn't something like this work?

```
//@qux[../@foo = 'x' or ../@bar='y']
```

Comment: No, but I have clarified what the requirements are with an example. I also realised I didn't need the `bar`, so I changed my question slightly.